# Why does removing `this` give unpredictable results when calling method on object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

The following snipped is modified from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics)

```
const person = {
  name: ['Bob', 'Smith'],
  age: 32,
  gender: 'male',
  interests: ['music', 'skiing'],
  bio: function() {
    console.log(name[0] + ' ' + this.name[1] + ' is ' + this.age + ' years old. He likes ' + this.interests[0] + ' and ' + this.interests[1] + '.');
  },
  greeting: function() {
    alert('Hi! I\'m ' + name[0] + '.');
  }
};

person.bio();
person.greeting();
```

Notice that I removed `this` from before `name[0]`. When I do this, `Bob` is output as `J`? WTF? :|

There isn't even a capital 'J' anywhere in the code? What is going on???

Comment: Cannot reproduce in my console.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/razugax/edit?js,console Does  this help? @SterlingArcher

Comment: name is global variable. Thats all. So you are accessing variable set somewhere on page.. Try to console.log(age). You get undefined.

Comment: Without `this`, `name` references the global scope. Print out `window.name`, and you'll see where the `J` comes from. In your linked snippet, the value of `window.name` is `JS Bin Output` (note the 0'th character is `J`).

Comment: @bigless is correct. `name[0]` in this case is accessing `window.name[0]` which is the string `"JS Bin ..."

Comment: That's the thing, if you see: http://jsbin.com/razugax/edit?js,console there is no other code. That is all code in its entirety...let me try in normal IDE outside of JSBin......

Comment: OMG! WTF! JSBin is sabotaging things now?!

Comment: Maybe not duplicate @SterlingArcher I do understand global vs local scoping. But, couldn't see that name was assigned to 'JSBin' in this case. It's not apparent.

Comment: @CodeFinity JSBin isn't doing anything other than setting a name for the tab. It's hardly being a saboteur.

Comment: @Paulpro IK Just being a bit overdramatic, but you must admit that that's not immediately apparent...

Comment: @CodeFinity Agreed, but you will find the similar behaviour on any page. All properties of `window` are accessible as globals in a browser (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window). So there are lots of other examples like `length` or `location`.

Comment: @Paulpro OIC So, window.name outputs basically title of the page... I didn't know that actually.

Comment: @CodeFinity Yeah, so hopefully you can see that JSBin specifically isn't doing anything strange. The strangeness you see would happen anywhere, even on your own pages. `name` isn't actually the title though (my bad for comparing it to an HTML `<title>` tag), it's often an empty string (in which case `name[0]` would be `undefined`), but it is usually set to some non-empty string for iframes.

Comment: @bigless `console.log(age);` should throw a Reference Error, not output `undefined`, unless there actually is a global (or any other accessible scope) called `age` with the value `undefined`.

Comment: @Paulpro you also probably know what I would to say.. But you are right. I thought undefined variable reference, not undefined as value.

Answer (score -1):

On jsbin, if you do `console.log(name)`, you will get `"JS Bin Output "`.  `name[0]` is therefor `"J"`.

http://jsbin.com/zaquvipuma/1/edit?js,console

Comment: This doesn't explain why there is a difference (e.g. property reference vs identifier resolution).

Comment: Yeah, this is all just a result of JSBin being strange.

Comment: Yes, that does pretty much clear up my bafflement about JSBin. I actually didn't try it in normal VS Code - only there, else I might have figured it out.